# Why does Hibernate map BIGINT to BigInteger

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdbc

In most databases a BIGINT is a 64bit integer. Does anyone know why Hibernate maps these to BigInteger instead of Long? I can handle these well but I'm just curious.

You can see their default mapping for this type in Dialect.java. I even found a hibernate issue but there are no comments indicating why this would be the case.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7318

I assume there must be a reason for this choice but I haven't had any success with google.

Also, what would be the impact of subclassing my databases dialect and overriding this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Quite probably because `BIGINT`s can be unsigned ([in MySQL at least](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html), if not in other RDBMSs).

The only Java type that can hold the full range of a 64-bit unsigned integer is `BigInteger`.  It would be incorrect to use a `long` for this, as this would convert 18446744073709551615 (2<sup>64</sup> - 1) to -1.

Comment: Yes but I would think that since I am setting the dialect to PostgreSQL that it would map to a long. Is there any way to global change this?

Comment: Worse, it maps Long -> bigint when it serializes and then can't get the values back out of the DDL it created.  I consider this to be a huge bug.   This happens /even when you set the scalar type in a query to Long./

Comment: While technically true, a lot of use cases do not (or will never) use the full range of BIGINT, so a Long will suffice. For example, if there are 2^64 - 1 people on earth, we've got much bigger problems to worry about than the next ID in the database. ;-) See also https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7318